# Variable randomly becomes null before input is even taken

Tags: c, ncurses

So, here is my problem. I am using ncurses, and when I press the up or down button, it says up arrow, and so I expect to move on in to my while loop, and take further input. The problem is, the variable input somehow in this process becomes NULL and it exists. Why is that? What I want is for it print up or down arrow, and the program to proceed normally.

```
int ch;
char input[100];
initscr();
raw();
keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
noecho();
ch = getch();
if(ch== KEY_UP)
    printf("\nUp Arrow"); fflush(stdout);

if(ch== KEY_DOWN)
    printf("\ndown Arrow");fflush(stdout);

endwin();
```

Comment: Where is `input` defined?

Comment: @templatetypedef check now

Comment: Note that despite the indentation, the two `fflush(stdout);` calls are both made unconditionally.  You need braces (or commas in place of semicolons — ick!) to make them conditional.

Comment: For `input` to become NULL requires major mishandling of something.  When you say 'it is null', what do you mean, precisely?  That you get a NULL from `fgets()`?  Or that when you print the address `input` it is zero — in the debugger, or in a `printf()` statement?  Incidentally, it is generally best to end output with a newline; begin the output with a newline if you want double spacing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it enters the if statement, so input gets a null from fgets

Comment: No, no, no...you're misinterpreting what happens.  When `fgets()` returns NULL, it means that either EOF was detected on the stream, or an error has occurred on the stream.  It does not mean that `input` has been set to NULL.  Granted, if all goes well, the return value from `fgets()` will be the pointer passed as the first argument (`input` in your code).  But the return being NULL does not mean that `input` has been set to NULL!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am writing my own shell, and all I wish to do is identify if a user has pressed the up key, or down key, so I can cycle through history. I cant use readline, so I am forced to use curses, and all I am trying to do with that code is simply set a flag true if a user presses the up button so I can continue on with my day. Instead, it becomes NULL and there is a huge gap on my screen. Please give me a hand here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Complete Example](http://sscce.org/)) based on your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curses.h>

int main(void)
{
    int ch;
    char input[100];

    initscr();
    raw();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    noecho();
    ch = getch();
    endwin();

    if (ch== KEY_UP)
        printf("\nUp Arrow\n");

    if (ch== KEY_DOWN)
        printf("\ndown Arrow\n");

    fflush(stdout);

    while(1)
    {
        if (fgets(input, sizeof (input), stdin) == NULL) 
        {
            printf("Early exit\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        printf("Read: %s", input);
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    printf("Late exit\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, it correctly detects if I use the up or down arrow keys, reporting it after I've called `endwin()` rather than before.  The `fflush()` calls would not normally be necessary, but it seems that the standard output is fully buffered rather than line buffered after you finish with `curses`, which is a little surprising.  (I'm testing on Mac OS X 10.8.2.)

The other trick I've used is diagnostic prints so I know what's happening where.  I called the program `curses`, and when I ran it, the screen cleared; then I typed an up arrow (in this case), then `sssddd` and return, then <kbd>Control-D</kbd> to indicate end of input (EOF), and the rest of the output was:

```
$ ./curses

Up Arrow
sssddd
Read: sssddd
Early exit
$
```

It is all behaving as I'd expect except for the buffering on standard output.  There isn't a way to get to the `Late exit` print statement in this program.

Comment: I am a using Mac, netbeans, and I got early exit. 







Up Arrow
Early exit

RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1s)

Comment: I wouldn't know how to use NetBeans — any more than I do XCode or Eclipse.  I don't have an explanation for why you're getting 'Early exit' immediately.  I don't think the terminal program you're using should be a factor (but I'm using `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal`).  I don't think the shell should be a factor (but I'm using `/bin/sh`, aka `bash`).  What happens if you compile in NetBeans and run direct from the terminal?

Comment: Which terminal application?  Which version of Mac OS X?  When I do `stty -g`, I get: `gfmt1:cflag=4b00:iflag=6b02:lflag=200005cb:oflag=3:discard=f:dsusp=19:eof=4:eol=ff:eol2=ff:erase=7f:intr=3:kill=18:lnext=16:min=1:quit=1c:reprint=12:start=11:status=14:stop=13:susp=1a:time=0:werase=17:ispeed=9600:ospeed=9600`.  Use: `echo stty -g $(stty -g) > sane; chmod +x sane` to record your current tty settings.  Then use `stty -g ...` where the dots are replaced by the string I just pasted.  Then run the program and see if it makes any difference. You can reinstate your settings with `./sane`.

Answer (score -2):

As stated input is undefined. Also, fgets is used for file input streams, not for reading the std input stream. (Use gets instead)

Comment: From `man gets`: "Never use gets(). Because it is impossible to tell without knowing the data in advance how many characters gets() will read, and because gets() will continue to store characters past the end of the buffer, it is extremely dangerous to use. It has been used to break computer security. Use fgets() instead."

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I completely forgot about gets() not enforcing bounds. So, listen to the people above don't use gets().